# Random interval number

Tags: javascript

I modified this countdown script to actually count up.

Now it changes the innerHTML of the div "container" every 300 ms.

How can i change that 300ms to be a random number between 300 and 2000?

Thanks so much for all your help :P

Greetz,
Camillo

```
var time = 1; //How long (in seconds) to countdown
function countDown(){
time++;

gett("container").innerHTML = time;
if(time == 0){
window.location = page;
}
}
function gett(id){
if(document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(id);
if(document.all) return document.all.id;
if(document.layers) return document.layers.id;
if(window.opera) return window.opera.id;
}
function init(){
if(gett('container')){
setInterval(countDown, 300); // here instead of 300 a random number between 300 and 2000
gett("container").innerHTML = time;
}
else{
setTimeout(init, 50);
}
}
```

Comment: An irrelevant personal thought: I guess that writing unindented code is better than using random indentation levels as others do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace with: `( 300+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1700) )`

**EDIT AFTER YOUR COMMENT:**

```
function countDown(){
  gett("container").innerHTML = ++time;
  if(time == 0){
      window.location = page;
  }
  else
      setTimeout(countDown,( 300+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1700) ));
}
```

And you call it by using:

```
setTimeout(countDown,( 300+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1700) ))
```

or simply `countDown()`

Oh, and you should know that accepting answers will increase your chances of getting "more of them" :)

Comment: Thanks Cristy for this kind answer :) With your script every time the page is reloaded, it generates a random number, which will be inserted in the interval. I need to have some sort of on-the-fly changing: Every time the interval is executed, it should be another number. It would be great if you could point me in the right direction :) Thanks in advance

Comment: I've had this same problem too. You should replace setInterval function with a recursive setTimeout :D